# Flutter setState causes infinite rendering

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myfitnesstrainer/logic/firestore_services.dart';
import 'package:myfitnesstrainer/models/user.dart';
import 'package:myfitnesstrainer/models/user_repository.dart';
import 'package:myfitnesstrainer/screens/loading_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class DistributePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // final User currentUser;
  const DistributePage();

  @override
  _DistributePageState createState() => _DistributePageState();
}

class _DistributePageState extends State<DistributePage> {
      FirestoreServices _firestoreServices = new FirestoreServices();
    bool isLoading=true;
    User curUser= new User();
    
    Future<User> getGoogleContent(UserRepository auth) async {
    var auth_user = await auth.getUser();
    print(auth_user.uid); //This print
    curUser.userID = auth_user.uid;
    curUser.name = auth_user.displayName;
    curUser.email = auth_user.email;
    curUser.imageUrl = auth_user.photoUrl;
    curUser =await _firestoreServices.saveUser(curUser);
   setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
          
    });

    return curUser;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserRepository auth = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
    getGoogleContent(auth);

    void logout() async {
      await auth.signOut();
    }

    return  isLoading ? LoadingScreen() :  Scaffold(appBar:AppBar(title:Text("Giriş")), body: 
      IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.signal_cellular_4_bar),onPressed: logout)
    );
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is save my user data to firebase and show a loading screen while doing so. It works however my print statement inside my function is keep getting called infinetly. I know its related to setState but I don't understand why it keeps rendering and calling that function. I would be glad if someone can tell me why I keep getting that printed userid in console.

Comment: Rule #1: Do not include business logic in widgets.

Comment: setState triggers build method everytime, so put your function in initstate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently calling `getGoogleContent` in the `build` method. Calling `setState` triggers a new rebuild. Since you're essentially calling `setState` in `build` by calling `getGoogleContent` in `build`, you've created an infinite loop.

To solve this, move `getGoogleContent(auth);` to `initState` so that it is only called once and rebuilds won't trigger this method again:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getGoogleContent(auth);
}
```

While your current method of showing a loading screen while data is loading is valid, [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) removes much of the complexity of your current method and prevents mistakes like this one from happening.